# Using Rails 3.1 with DataTables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

In Rails 3.1 what is the recommended gem to integrate with [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net) ?

Answer (score 10):

I'm using the `jquery-datatables-rails` gem with bootstrap (twitter-bootstrap-rails gem) and it is perfect. The railscast episode on it is great -- but don't put the gem in your assets group or it will not work when deploying to heroku (since the assets group is not used in production).

Put this line in your gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
```

and run:

```
bundle install
```

Also, make sure to put this line in your application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Add this to your application.js

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

And this one if you are using bootstrap:

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

Add this to your application.css:

```
*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

Or this one if you are using bootstrap:

```
*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

And if you are using bootstrap add this to your js.coffee file for your controller you are using datatables in:

If you are using fluid containers:

```
#// For fluid containers
$('#dashboard').dataTable({
  "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
  "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
});
```

If you are using fixed width containers:

```
#// For fixed width containers
$('.datatable').dataTable({
  "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
  "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ryan Bates' RailsCast on the topic (http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables)
he uses jquery-datatables-rails (https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but this is one that is available: https://github.com/gryphon/simple_datatables .

Comment: [simpe_datatables](https://github.com/gryphon/simple_datatables) uses [meta_search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) which is being deprecated. I've used it but i had some issues with it in pagination and using more than one table. Now i'm implementing my own gem.

Answer (score 0):

The following gem link may be relevant: https://github.com/artellectual/rails-datatables

This gem is a fork of the simple_datatables gem (mentioned by Allan) but it also supports pagination with kaminari and searching table data with ajax using the meta search gem.